# JOI library is throwing error with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, validation, joi

I'm using JOI in Shopify template project. Here I installed latest version of JOI, yet I'm getting error for every function like:

> TypeError: JOI.array is not a function

Please find the code below:

```
import * as JOI from "joi";
const addProductValidator = JOI.array().items(
  JOI.object().keys({
    catalogue_item_id: JOI.string()
      .pattern(new RegExp(REGEX_FORMULA.MONGO_OBJ_ID_VALIDATOR))
      .required(),
    sub_categories: JOI.array().items(JOI.string().required()),
    catalogue_item_description: JOI.object()
      .keys({
        name: JOI.string().optional(),
        symbol: JOI.string().optional(),
        short_description: JOI.string().optional(),
        long_description: JOI.string().optional(),
        images: JOI.array().items(JOI.string().optional()),
        price: JOI.object()
          .keys({
            is_selling_price_exclusive_of_gst: JOI.boolean().required(),
            max_retail_price: JOI.number().required(),
            selling_price: JOI.number().required(),
            sgst_tax_rate: JOI.number().optional(),
            cgst_tax_rate: JOI.number().optional(),
            igst_tax_rate: JOI.number().optional(),
            total_tax_rate: JOI.number().required(),
          })
          .required(),
      })
      .required(),
    inventory: JOI.object()
      .keys({
        unit_denomination: JOI.string().required(),
        unit_value: JOI.number().required(),
        quantity: JOI.number().required(),
      })
      .required(),
    item_policies: JOI.object()
      .keys({
        returnable: JOI.boolean().required(),
        return_window: JOI.number().required(),
        seller_pickup_return: JOI.boolean().required(),
        cancellable: JOI.boolean().required(),
        cod_availability: JOI.boolean().required(),
        time_to_ship: JOI.number().required(),
        max_sale_quantity: JOI.number().required(),
        min_sale_quantity: JOI.number().required(),
      })
      .required(),
    serviceability: JOI.object()
      .keys({
        radius: JOI.number().required(), // make 0 as default
        pincodes: JOI.array().items(JOI.number().required()), // make [0] for all pincodes 
      })
      .required(),
  })
);

export { addProductValidator };
```

Detailed Error:

```
2023-07-01 13:22:41 │ backend  │ TypeError: JOI.array is not a function
2023-07-01 13:22:41 │ backend  │     at file:///Users/soham/projects/nextronn-products/ondc-shopify-plugin/ondc-bridge-app/web/backend/Middleware/Products.validator.js:7:33
2023-07-01 13:22:41 │ backend  │     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:192:25)
2023-07-01 13:22:41 │ backend  │     at async DefaultModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:246:24)
2023-07-01 13:22:41 │ backend  │     at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:40:7)
2023-07-01 13:22:41 │ backend  │     at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:66:12)
```

Is it because I'm using ES6 in this project? Can anyone please help me to understand the issue?

Comment: You should try `import Joi from "joi";`